# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.lib.recfunctions'

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed `statsmodels`in Python but now the following error occur:

```
runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-19-e8fdc416f3c8>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py", line 49, in <module>

import statsmodels.api as sm
File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .tools import add_constant, categorical

File "/home/mattes/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 6, in <module>
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nprf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.lib.recfunctions'
```

Does someone has an idea how to solve it?

I use Python 3.6 and Spyder 3.2.8 with Anaconda in Ubuntu 16.04

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have numpy? What happens if you put `import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)` into the interpreter? Did you install `statsmodels` with `pip` or `conda`?

Comment: Did you installed numpy, if not , installed pip install numpy

Comment: Yes I have it installed, teh output is: `import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)
1.14.3 `

Comment: And is an error thrown when you do `import numpy.lib.recfunctions`?

Comment: Wait, statmodels is in a virtual environment `anaconda3/envs/test`. I'm betting `numpy` is in your main environment. You'll have to either install `numpy` in your virtual env, or install statmodels in your main environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sadly it still occur. I tried `sudo import numpy.lib.recfunctions` but nothing changed.

Comment: That was true,now I installed `statsmodels`in my main environment and `numpy`in my virtual environment but it still occur :/

Comment: Oh and I used conda for the installation